# How do I use the contents of the buffer to save some typing/autocomplete on the command line?

Tags: command-line

When editing a buffer and initiating a search-and-replace, I use `:s/oldword/newword/g`

Now the word 'oldword' will be in the buffer I am editing, and sometimes it is a long word.

It would be helpful if I was able to auto-complete somehow the words 'oldword' and 'newword' from the contents of the buffer to save some typing, say by typing just `:s/ol` then TAB to cycle through matches in the buffer, and then similarly for 'newword'.

Is something like this possible without plugin ?

In general, is there a way of getting completion suggestions from the current buffer to assemble the `:` command line ?

Comment: while in `:` command mode `<C-r><C-w>` yanks the word under the cursor into the command line.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't know if there's a way to do exactly what you are asking, but there are two alternatives I think are close enough:

1. If you open a command-line window with `q:` (from normal mode) or `CTRL-F` (from command-line mode), you can edit your commands with the full power of Vim. This includes using `CTRL-P` for autocompletion, which depending on the value of your `'complete'` setting, can look for matches in your current buffer (include `.` in the value of the setting for that).
2. Not autocompletion, but if you have the long word under the cursor while editing the buffer, you could yank it first, and then paste it into the command line with `CTRL-R {register}` when editing the command line.

Comment: If you have the long word under the cursor while editing the buffer, you don’t need to yank it first: you can use `<C-R>=` to paste from the special expression register. I have `cnoremap <C-Space> <C-R>=expand("<cword> ")<CR>` in `$MYVIMRC`.

Answer (score 4):

With `set incsearch` you can complete  using `ctrl-L` in `/` and `:s/` command lines (see `:help /_CTRL-L`).

Comment: Use this in combination with `ctrl-G` to jump to the word you want to match.

Comment: For some reason, this works with / but not with :s/

Comment: @user3203476, perhaps you are using neovim (in which case see inccommand)

Answer (score 3):

Ideas:

- yank the word and paste it while typing (`<C-r>"`)
- type the command in the buffer and use `:exec getline('.')` to run it

I prefer the `q:`/`<C-f>` from the other answer though.